# Hyperledger Fabric: Chain file does not exist at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-chain.pem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we get this error when trying to enroll a user against an intermediate CA:

```
root@dda3b6a7d56c:/home# fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://ica-admin:ica-adminpw@ica-jnj:7054 -M ica-admin
2019/03/21 16:47:27 [INFO] Created a default configuration file at /root/.fabric-ca-client/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
2019/03/21 16:47:27 [INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
2019/03/21 16:47:27 [INFO] encoded CSR
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 0 - Chain file does not exist at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-chain.pem
```

we started our intermediate CA (`ica-jnj` server) like this:

```
root@710d3b5984cd:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server# fabric-ca-server start -b ica-admin:ica-adminpw -u http://admin:adminpw@rca-jnj:7054
```

we are not using any TLS. how can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of this error is that the files `ca-cert.pem` and `ca-key.pem` were not deleted before starting the intermediate CA. When an instance of `fabric-ca` is created, it automatically comes with above 2 files inside `/etc/hyperledger/fabric` folder. **These files need to be deleted for an intermediate CA**. Once you do that, after starting the `fabric-ca-server` you should see `ca-chain.pem` file in the directory. The chain file can be inspected by running:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca-chain.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout
```

and will show the chain from intermediate CA to root CA

Comment: Hi @morpheus. Could you please elaborate on this? where can we read information about this procedure? I'm facing the same issue and if I delete those files, I get the error `CN 'fabric-ca-server' cannot be specified for an intermediate CA. Remove CN from CSR section for enrollment of intermediate CA to be successful` even though I am not explicitly indicating a common name when launching the intermediate CA. I can say that ca-chain.pem is never created in my intermediate CA. I am using fabric-ca 1.4.2 images.

Comment: My guess is that its getting this CN from the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file you are using. When fabric-ca starts it auto-loads a config file known as fabric-ca-server-config.yaml. https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serverconfig.html. In this file is a ca->name section which I suspect is set to fabric-ca-server.